# Can we express all functions in the exponential family with this differential equation?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, soft-question, exponential-function

Using the "prime" notation for differentiation $$f'(x) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\{f\}(x)\\f''(x) = \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}\{f\}(x)\\\vdots\\f^{(k)}(x) = \frac{\partial^k }{\partial x^k}\{f\}(x)$$

Consider the differential equation:

$$\sum_{k=0}^N P_k(t)f^{(k)}(t) - g(t) = 0$$

Where $\{P_0,\cdots,P_N\}$ are polynomials, $f$ is the function we want to solve for.

A general function in the exponential family is:

$$f(x) = P_1(x) e^{P_2(x)}$$

For two given polynomials $P_1,P_2$. Now allow them to not be same as $P_k$ above.

Will we be able to express all functions in the exponential family using this differential equation?

---

***Own work:***

I have calculated $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\{P_1(x) e^{P_2(x)}\} = {P_1}'(x)e^{P_2(x)} + P_1(x)P_2(x)e^{P(x)} = \\ \underset{P_3(x)}{\underbrace{({P_1}'(x)+P_1(x)P_2(x))}}e^{P_2(x)}=P_3(x)e^{P_2(x)}$$

So we can guarantee that differentiation on such a function keeps us inside the family (closure).

But is this enough? Is it perhaps even overkill?

Comment: What are the assumptions on $g$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Good question, I have not thought about it. Let us assume we can choose $g$ and the $P_k$'s freely in order to find an equation for our exponential family $f$. Wait.. then we could just set $1\cdot f(x) + 0\cdot (f'+f'' + \cdots) = g(x)$. That would not be very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact every function of the form $P_1(t) e^{P_2(t)}$ is a solution of a **homogeneous** linear differential equation with polynomial coefficients.

Note that if $f(t) = P_1(t) e^{P_2(t)}$, $f'(t) - P_2'(t) f(t) = P_1'(t) e^{P_2(t)}$, and $P_1'$ has degree one less than $P_1$ (if $P_1$ is not constant).
Thus if $P_1$ has degree $n$, $f$ is a solution of the differential equation $T^{n+1} f = 0$
where $T$ is the differential operator $f \mapsto f' - P' f$.

Comment: Aha, so we can get away with the special case $g=0$ also?